# Adding and retrieving items from list

Tags: python, python-2.x

Could someone take a look at my code and see whats up?

I'm new to coding. Probably obvious. So I want to add 5 names to list and then print the third name from the list. Why isn't this working:

```
list=[]

def lol():
    return input("Give the name you want to add to the list.")

a=lol()
b=lol()
c=lol()
d=lol()
e=lol()

variables=[a,b,c,d,e]

list.append(variables)
print list[2]
```

Comment: `print list[2]` this question shouldn't be tagged with [tag:python-3.x]

Comment: What's the point of `list`? Why not just do `variables[2]`?

Comment: Yeah I could do variables[2], but why is list[2] not working, just trying to learn...

Comment: Just print `list` and `variables` and you will see what they contain which will explain what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

## Logical issues with your code

You will have a problem accessing an element in third position of the list because there isn't one. When you call `append()` the list you are passing will be treated like one element so it will put in first or position 0 all the list.

```
print list
[[1, 2, 3 , 4, 5]]
```

Looking at the output, you can see that you have a **list of lists** and with only one element in position 0, but you are trying to retrieve the one in position 2 and python correctly replies `IndexError: list index out of range`.
In case you want that your list to be populated with every element in `variables` use `extend()` method of this data structure.
Otherwise, first retrieve the list in position 0 and then look directly in it in this way: `list[0][2]`.

#### Note

Try not using reserved keywords like list, dict and so on because they are used for calling some built-in functions of Python language. Your code will be unreadable otherwise.

Comment: @AksO, try in the Python interpreter console, `dir(__builtins__)` to get an idea of possible reserved words. Call also `help()` and then `keywords`.